# Generate a base64 encoded random string in Ansible

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to to register variable in Ansible

```bash
ENCRYPTION_KEY=$(head -c 32 /dev/urandom | base64)
```

I try this one but there is error

```yaml
- name: ENCRYPTION_KEY
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['only-master-1']
  command: head -c 32 /dev/urandom | base64
  register: ENCRYPTION_KEY
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from the fact that the `command` module have those limitations, from its documentation [synopsis](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#synopsis):

> The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables like `$HOSTNAME` and operations like `"*"`, `"<"`, `">"`, `"|"`, `";"` and `"&"` will not work. Use the [ansible.builtin.shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-shell-module) module if you need these features.

So, if you really want to achieve it this way, use the `shell` module instead.

---

**This said,** do not let your sysadmin background get in the way when writing Ansible playbooks, as there are way better ideas to generate a random, 32 characters, base 64 encoded string, for example, the purposed [`community.general.random_string` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/random_string_lookup.html).

Here is an example of usage, but you are free to use a `set_fact` to save it in a variable:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{
        lookup(
          'community.general.random_string',
          length=32,
          base64=True
        )
      }}
```

This would yield something like:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: LF5tfXg4ZzNFcy1EVXFwe2dKKV4oXj9IPFIjQHFJOzg=
```